# python selenium : how to use the Chrome translate function in a headless state?

Tags: python, selenium

Hello thank you for reading my article

I want to translate english to korean on website.

I used chrome translate function and capturing element, but element picture is cut off, because element viewport is partially invisible. so I add 'headless' option and success capturing full element but translate not working... Below is an example

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {"en": "ko"},
    "translate": {"enabled": "true"}
}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
# if I turn on 'headless' option, translate function didn't work!!
# if I turn off 'headless' option, capturing image is cut off!!
# options.add_argument('headless')  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 100000)

profile_url = 'https://money.cnn.com/quote/profile/profile.html?symb='
ticker = 'fubo'

driver.get(profile_url + ticker)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cnnBody > div.cnnBody_Left.wsodContent')
element.screenshot(ticker + '_profile.png')
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

preference is not supported for headless browser

As of Feb , 2021

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Headless chrome doesn't support preferrences setting . You can use command line arguments only.

the full list of supported arguments are :

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Try:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --lang=en --enable-experimental-accessibility-language-detection-dynamic --enable-experimental-accessibility-language-detection
```

Comment: thats too bad. is there any update on this tho